# Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("todoscreen", Instance of 'ScreenArguments') in the _WidgetsAppState. FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, navigation

Okay so the reason this error is weird is that it wasn't there till i added bluetooth functionality to my project. If i can't resolve this i might have to make my app from scratch an as a flutter beginner, it took me weeks to get this far. let me just describe my app: It is a health app paired with a wearable band. After login, the user is prompted to connect to a device and once they connect, HomeScreen() is returned which shows the temp and pulse data sent from arduino through bluetooth. For now,pulse is hardcoded but temp is sent from sensor to app, and updated to firestore then retrieved and displayed.
So the app has both a user and a caretaker interface.

here is main.dart

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/btInitialize.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/welcome.dart';
import 'package:vitality/components/route.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff222831),
        accentColor: Color(0xff00adb5),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color: Colors.black),
          headline2: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 60.0, fontFamily: 'CrimsonText', color: Colors.black),
          headline3: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0, fontFamily: 'Lora', color: Colors.white),
          headline4: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color: Colors.white),
          headline5: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 85.0, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color: Colors.black),
          headline6: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      initialRoute: Welcome.id,
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGen.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

here is route.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/chatbot.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/todo.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/welcome.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/register.dart';
import 'package:vitality/components/ScreenArguments.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/btInitialize.dart';
import 'package:vitality/components/HomeArguments.dart';

class RouteGen {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case btInit.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          final argument = args as ScreenArguments;
          return btInit(
            docid: argument.docid,
            isCaretaker: argument.isCaretaker,
          );
        });
      case Welcome.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Welcome());
      case HomeScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          final argument = args as HomeArgs;
          return HomeScreen(
              docid: argument.docid,
              isCaretaker: argument.isCaretaker,
              currentDevice: argument.currentDevice);
        });
      case LoginScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen());
      case Register.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Register());
      case ChatBot.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          final argument = args as ScreenArguments;
          return ChatBot(
            docid: argument.docid,
            isCaretaker: argument.isCaretaker,
          );
        });
      case Todo.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          final argument = args as ScreenArguments;
          return Todo(
            docid: argument.docid,
            isCaretaker: argument.isCaretaker,
          );
        });
    }
  }
}
```

since i have to pass multiple arguments i have a screenarguments class to pass docid, and isCaregiver (bool) between screens. and the first homescreen needs a device parameters passed so just for home i made a different class.
Here theyy are

```
class ScreenArguments {
  final String docid;
  final bool isCaretaker;

  ScreenArguments({this.docid, this.isCaretaker});
}

import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

class HomeArgs {
  final String docid;
  final bool isCaretaker;
  final BluetoothDevice currentDevice;

  HomeArgs({this.docid, this.isCaretaker, this.currentDevice});
}
```

WHen login button is pressed, this is the screen it goes to
btinitialize.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/connection.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/homescreen.dart';

class btInit extends StatelessWidget {
  final String docid;
  final bool isCaretaker;
  static const String id = 'btinit';
  btInit({@required this.docid, @required this.isCaretaker});
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.requestEnable(),
        builder: (context, future) {
          if (future.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: Center(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.bluetooth_disabled,
                    size: 200.0,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else if (future.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            print('bluetooth turned on');
            // return MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page');
            return Home(docid: docid, isCaretaker: isCaretaker);
          } else {
            return Home(docid: docid, isCaretaker: isCaretaker);
          }
        },
        // child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final String docid;
  final bool isCaretaker;
  Home({this.docid, this.isCaretaker});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          toolbarHeight: 50.0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            'HEALTH TRACKER',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          )),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage(
              'https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Blur-Phone-Wallpaper-1080x2340-011-340x550.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(.7), BlendMode.dstATop),
        )),
        child: SelectBondedDevicePage(
          Upload: (device1) {
            BluetoothDevice device = device1;
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return HomeScreen(
                    docid: docid,
                    isCaretaker: isCaretaker,
                    currentDevice: device,
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

First it asks user to turn on bluetooth. then it returns the class SELECTBONDEDDEVICEPAGE Which is the device and a button that when pressed, take you to home screen.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
connection.dart
This page is the code to discover devices. Theres not much UI stuff here.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

enum _DeviceAvailability {
  maybe,
  yes,
}

class _DeviceWithAvailability extends BluetoothDevice {
  BluetoothDevice device;
  _DeviceAvailability availability;
  int rssi;

  _DeviceWithAvailability(this.device, this.availability, [this.rssi]);
}

class SelectBondedDevicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool checkAvailability;
  final Function Upload;
  final String docid;
  final bool isCaretaker;
  static const String id = 'connect';
  const SelectBondedDevicePage(
      {this.checkAvailability = true,
      this.Upload,
      this.docid,
      this.isCaretaker});

  @override
  _SelectBondedDevicePage createState() => new _SelectBondedDevicePage();
}

class _SelectBondedDevicePage extends State<SelectBondedDevicePage> {
  List<_DeviceWithAvailability> devices = List<_DeviceWithAvailability>();

  // Availability
  StreamSubscription<BluetoothDiscoveryResult> _discoveryStreamSubscription;
  bool _isDiscovering;

  _SelectBondedDevicePage();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _isDiscovering = widget.checkAvailability;

    if (_isDiscovering) {
      _startDiscovery();
    }

    // Setup a list of the bonded devices
    FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
        .getBondedDevices()
        .then((List<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices) {
      setState(() {
        devices = bondedDevices
            .map(
              (device) => _DeviceWithAvailability(
                device,
                widget.checkAvailability
                    ? _DeviceAvailability.maybe
                    : _DeviceAvailability.yes,
              ),
            )
            .toList();
      });
    });
  }

  void _startDiscovery() {
    _discoveryStreamSubscription =
        FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.startDiscovery().listen((r) {
      setState(() {
        Iterator i = devices.iterator;
        while (i.moveNext()) {
          var _device = i.current;
          if (_device.device == r.device) {
            _device.availability = _DeviceAvailability.yes;
            _device.rssi = r.rssi;
          }
        }
      });
    });

    _discoveryStreamSubscription.onDone(() {
      setState(() {
        _isDiscovering = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Avoid memory leak (`setState` after dispose) and cancel discovery
    _discoveryStreamSubscription?.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }

//build returns list of bletooth devices entries (name, and connect button) with an on tap method Upload()
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<BluetoothDeviceListEntry> list = devices
        .map(
          (_device) => BluetoothDeviceListEntry(
            device: _device.device,
            onTap: () {
              widget.Upload(_device.device);
            },
          ),
        )
        .toList();
    return ListView(
      children: list,
    );
  }
}

class BluetoothDeviceListEntry extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTap;
  final BluetoothDevice device;

  BluetoothDeviceListEntry({this.onTap, @required this.device});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: onTap,
      leading: Icon(Icons.devices),
      title: Text(device.name ?? "Unknown device"),
      subtitle: Text(device.address.toString()),
      trailing: FlatButton(
        child: Text('Connect'),
        onPressed: onTap,
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And finally, when the button is pressed, it goes to homescreen with parameters docid, isCaretaker, and hte device.
[image: 3]
homescreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:vitality/components/bottomAppBar.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:vitality/components/biom.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'home_screen';
  final String docid;
  final bool isCaretaker;
  final BluetoothDevice currentDevice;
  HomeScreen(
      {@required this.docid,
      @required this.isCaretaker,
      @required this.currentDevice});
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

_callNumber() async {
  const number = '8606535166'; //set the number here
  bool res = await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(number);
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var pulse;
  var temp;
  static final clientID = 0;
  BluetoothConnection connection;
  String _messageBuffer = '';
  bool isConnecting = true;
  bool get isConnected => connection != null && connection.isConnected;
  bool isDisconnecting = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BluetoothConnection.toAddress(widget.currentDevice.address)
        .then((_connection) {
      print('Connected to the device');
      print('device is ${widget.currentDevice}');
      connection = _connection;
      setState(() {
        isConnecting = false;
        isDisconnecting = false;
      });
      connection.input.listen(_onDataReceived).onDone(() {
        if (isDisconnecting) {
          print('Disconnecting locally!');
        } else {
          print('Disconnected remotely!');
        }
        if (this.mounted) {
          setState(() {});
        }
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Cannot connect, exception occurred');
      print(error);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Avoid memory leak (`setState` after dispose) and disconnect
    if (isConnected) {
      isDisconnecting = true;
      connection.dispose();
      connection = null;
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data) {
    // Allocate buffer for parsed data
    int backspacesCounter = 0;
    data.forEach((byte) {
      if (byte == 8 || byte == 127) {
        backspacesCounter++;
      }
    });
    Uint8List buffer = Uint8List(data.length - backspacesCounter);
    int bufferIndex = buffer.length;

    // Apply backspace control character
    backspacesCounter = 0;
    for (int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (data[i] == 8 || data[i] == 127) {
        backspacesCounter++;
      } else {
        if (backspacesCounter > 0) {
          backspacesCounter--;
        } else {
          buffer[--bufferIndex] = data[i];
        }
      }
    }

    // Create message if there is new line character
    String dataString = String.fromCharCodes(buffer);
    print('$dataString');
    changePulse(int.parse(dataString));
    int index = buffer.indexOf(13);
    if (~index != 0) {
      setState(() {
        _messageBuffer = dataString.substring(index);
        //print('In message buffer is $_messageBuffer');
      });
    } else {
      _messageBuffer = (backspacesCounter > 0
          ? _messageBuffer.substring(
              0, _messageBuffer.length - backspacesCounter)
          : _messageBuffer + dataString);
    }
  }

  void _sendMessage(String text) async {
    text = text.trim();
    if (text.length > 0) {
      try {
        connection.output.add(utf8.encode(text + "\r\n"));
        await connection.output.allSent;
      } catch (e) {
        // Ignore error, but notify state
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }

  changePulse(int dataString) {
    main
        .doc(widget.docid)
        .update({'pulse': dataString})
        .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(
        'in homescreen each iis ${widget.docid}, ${widget.isCaretaker},${widget.currentDevice}');
    _sendMessage('1');
    print('got here');
    CollectionReference main = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('maindb');
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          toolbarHeight: 50.0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            'HEALTH TRACKER',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          )),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage(
              'https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Blur-Phone-Wallpaper-1080x2340-011-340x550.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(.7), BlendMode.dstATop),
        )),
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 100.0),
              Text(widget.docid),
              Text({widget.isCaretaker}.toString()),
              biom(which: 'pulse', image: 'pulse', docid: widget.docid),
              RoundBorderText(text: 'PULSE'),
              biom(which: 'temperature', image: 'temper', docid: widget.docid),
              RoundBorderText(text: 'TEMPERATURE'),
              SizedBox(height: 30.0),
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('test call'),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    _callNumber();
                  })
            ]),
      ),
      **bottomNavigationBar**: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(
                'https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Blur-Phone-Wallpaper-1080x2340-011-340x550.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(1), BlendMode.dstATop),
          )),
          child: bottomAppBar()),
    );
  }
}

class RoundBorderText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  RoundBorderText({this.text});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            // ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
        child: Text(text, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1));
  }
}
```

basically when it receives data from arduino it adds it to firestore nd displays it on screen also.
at the bottom is a bottomappbar which i extracted to a class.

**THE PROBLEM IS HERE.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vitality/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:vitality/components/ScreenArguments.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

class bottomAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  bottomAppBar({this.id});
  @override
  _bottomAppBarState createState() => _bottomAppBarState();
}

class _bottomAppBarState extends State<bottomAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('id in bottom is ${widget.id}');
    return BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.list),
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                print('to do pressed');
                print(docid);
                print(isCaretaker.toString());
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('todoscreen',
                    arguments: ScreenArguments(
                        docid: docid, isCaretaker: isCaretaker));
              }),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.data_usage),
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('home_screen',
                    arguments: ScreenArguments(
                        docid: widget.id, isCaretaker: isCaretaker));
              }),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('chat_screen',
                    arguments: ScreenArguments(
                        docid: widget.id, isCaretaker: isCaretaker));
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The bottom bar consists of 3 icons, a reminder icon, homescreen one and chatbot one. We are currently in homescreen but when the todo icon is pressed, it should go to the screen for that. This worked before i put it the bluetooth code but now i get this error:

Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("chat_screen", Instance of 'ScreenArguments') in the _WidgetsAppState.

for both the todo screen and chat screen.

here todo.dart code just so u can see it's initialized with necessary parameters

```
bool temp;
var todoid;
int number = 0;
final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Stream collectionStream =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo').snapshots();
CollectionReference main = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('maindb');
CollectionReference todo = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo');
final myController = TextEditingController();

class Todo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String docid;
  final bool isCaretaker;
  Todo({this.docid, this.isCaretaker});
  @override
  _TodoState createState() => _TodoState();
  static const String id = 'todoscreen';
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated as i am completely lost on what went wrong. (the bluetooth code is working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `Navigator.of(context)`, Flutter goes through the ancestors in the widget tree to find the nearest `Navigator`.

Now, you actually don't spcifically provide any `Navigator` widget in the tree, so where is your `Navigator` coming from ?

That's the `MaterialApp`.

Now, you have your main `MaterialApp` at the root.

But if you check your `btInit` widget, you have declared another `MaterialApp` in it. So when you call, `pushNamed('todoscreen')`, it is actually getting a hold of the `Navigator` from the `MaterialApp` of your `btInit` widget and not the main one.

Since, you only defined `onGenerateRoute` on the main `MaterialApp`, it is unable to resolve a request for the `todoscreen` route name.

Remove the `MaterialApp` inside your `btInit` widget and this should be resolved.

Comment: Wow, i can't believe i spent hours trying to solve this and all it took was me changing 2 words. Thank you so much!! I cannot express how indebted i am..i was going to remake this from scratch :)

Comment: Haha. Hey, it happens.